# Where to store global data in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

Where should I store information like admin's email, telephone number? I want admin to be able to change this data anytime they want.

Now, I have one model for this. It's called `AdminContact` and it allows only one row. I think it's not an appropriate way to do this. Moreover, it causes circular dependencies. For example, I can't use my model `email`, which contains all contact methods like `send_message_to_all_users`, `send_alert_to_admin` in models because of circular dependencies.

The way I do it now:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from models import AdminContact

def send_message_to_admin(subject,message):
    EmailMessage(subject,message,to=[AdminContact.objects.all()[0].email]).send()
```

Could you give me any recommendations how to treat this kind of data?

Comment: Isn't django built in `User` model what you need?

Comment: Django has users. Users have is_staff and is_superuser flags that you can use or you can add your own flag to designate admins. Users have email field and you can add more fields in a user profile model.

Comment: Django also has a built-in way to e-mail all admins. You're reinventing the wheel all over the place!

Comment: Two-Bit Alchemist: It would be more helpful if append a link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One fine way to do this is to put it inside your `settings.py` file like so :

`ADMIN_CONTACT = {email: 'foo@bar.com', phone: '0585522002'}`

Then you can access it anywhere by importing django settings :

```
from django.conf import settings 
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage

def send_message_to_admin(subject,message):
    EmailMessage(subject,message,to=[settings.ADMIN_CONTACT['email']]).send()
```

**Caveat :**

You can replace those values only by modifying the `settings.py` code.

**Other solutions :**

You can also use the base `User` model to get all superusers and mail them, or give a look at [django-constance](https://github.com/jazzband/django-constance) which permits you to store constants on db side, and editable from the `django-admin`.

Comment: Not sure why this answer was down voted. Put it in your settings like Maxime says and you can access it globally. Abstract sensitive info like this out of your base settings. If your code is in source control, make sure you `.gitignore` this sensitive file (or whatever source control you use).

Comment: @Maxime Thanks, I think that I will use django-constance since I want to store more data, for example settings like - how much cost translation of one page etc.